# Trouble reading a remote pdf from a NSArray content?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsrangeexception

I want to read some remote pdfs so I create an `NSArray` containing the urls, but when I try to read it I get this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

this is my code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CircularDetail"]) {

        CircularDetailViewController *circulardetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CircularControllerDetail"];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int row = [myIndexPath row];

        circulardetail.DetailModal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_SeccionCirculares[row], _circularfecha[row], _circularTitulo[row], _circularURL[row], nil];

        [self presentViewController:circulardetail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

in the detail I have this

```
- (void) loadRemotePdf
{
        NSURL  *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[_DetailModal objectAtIndex:3]];
        NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

        [self.webview loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

Comment: You have several arrays - what's in them? Which one fails? Log the array contents each time before you access the array. Check the array `count` before accessing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
CircularDetailViewController *circulardetail =
     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CircularControllerDetail"];
```

creates a *new* instance of the view controller. You probably want

```
CircularDetailViewController *circulardetail =
     (CircularDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

instead.

And you don't have to call `presentViewController` for a segue transition.

You should also note that any `nil` object in the argument list of

```
circulardetail.DetailModal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

*terminates* the list, so the array might be shorter than you expect.